# Redirect after posting in nodejs Error 'Can't set headers after they are sent'

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, callback

Redirect after posting in nodejs Error 'Can't set headers after they are sent'
Here is code

```
router.post('/newItem', function (req, res, next) {

  product.insertItem(req.body, req.files, function (err ,result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.redirect(307, '/home'); 
  });
});
```

This is module insertItem function

```
module.exports.insertItem = function (doc, file, callback) {

  mongo.item.insert(data, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(err, result);
  });
})
```

This always throw Error below

```
/Users/hello/Desktop/dev/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95 
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; }); 

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. 
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:690:11) 
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/hello/Desktop/dev/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:564:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.location (/Users/hello/Desktop/dev/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:678:8)
    at ServerResponse.redirect
```

How can I solve the problem..?

Comment: I think it`s very simple. Is there any things that I have misunderstand about nodejs? or express??

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with `res.redirect` when I had more code after the block in question.

I solved it with `return false` after the redirect.

In your case it would look like this:

`res.redirect(307, '/home'); 
return false;`