# Nodejs Redirect - Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

Referencing to this question that have no answers yet => [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479496/redirect-after-posting-in-nodejs-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

I can't redirect after verifying token in express nodejs.

```
app.post('/server', function(req,res, next){
    var idToken = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
        idToken = obj.idToken;
       firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
          .then(function(decodedToken) {
           var uid = decodedToken.uid;
           authenticationFlag = true;
           res.redirect('/profile');
         }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('ERROR IS:'+error);
            authenticationFlag = false;
       });
  });
  res.end('');
});
```

Error is: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Basically i want to redirect user to profile once he logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling res.end() before the promise was resolved, (because this is asynchronous code). res.end ends the response process.

When you are trying to call res.redirect in the promise scope, the objectis already closed.

Try moving the res.end() inside promise when the promise is already resolved.

```
app.post('/server', function(req,res, next){
    var idToken = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
        idToken = obj.idToken;
        firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
          .then(function(decodedToken) {
           var uid = decodedToken.uid;
           authenticationFlag = true;
           res.redirect('/profile');
           res.end();
         }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('ERROR IS:'+error);
            authenticationFlag = false;
            res.status(ERROR_CODE).end();
       });  
    });
});
```

Comment: try to redirect with 303 code res.redirect(303, '/profile')

Comment: it doesn't work, neither with GET. It works everywhere else but not in this specific function.

Comment: 303 code still deosn't redirect? are you redirecting to POST or GET?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is on the second from last line `res.end('')` this is being called before your asynchronous function `firebase.auth()` is being called.

From the documentation http://expressjs.com/en/api.html the `res.end` function is used to return a response quickly with no data, kind of like an empty return

> Use to quickly end the response without any data

So your logic is as below:

```js
console.log('start');

Promise.resolve('firebase results, after res.end is called!')
       .then(value => console.log(value))
       
console.log('This is ran before the Promise! Where the res.end is');
```

So your code "exits" before the promise from firebase can return.  Your solution is to remove the `res.end()` and add some error handling logic.

e.g. in the context of your question:

```
    app.post('/server', function(req,res, next){
    var idToken = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
        idToken = obj.idToken;
       firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
          .then(function(decodedToken) {
           var uid = decodedToken.uid;
           authenticationFlag = true;
           res.redirect('/profile');
         }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('ERROR IS:'+error);
            authenticationFlag = false;
            res.status(400).send('Wrong details');
       });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah! Error is gone but it's not redirecting towards **profile**. I have `console.log('redirecting to profile');` it prints the same but do not redirect.

Comment: I'll try locally

Comment: You need to use the firebase-admin package as this is where you can verify the token https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: I am using firebase admin package -> [My Server.js](https://pastebin.com/mNuTkKYv)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149961/discussion-between-noman-ali-and-peter-grainger).

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers did not worked for me (May be they work for you). So i have did something else. In my client file from where the token was being sent to **server**

I have redirected it there.

```
       $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:9615/server',

            data: '{"idToken": "'+idToken+'"}',
            type: 'POST',
            jsonpCallback: 'callback', // this is not relevant to the POST anymore
            success: function (data) {
               window.location = "profile";
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
            },
        });
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with `res.redirect` when there was more code in the particular function I was in.

My problem was solved with `return false` after the redirect.

For example,

`res.redirect('/profile');
return false;`